# Eloquent don't quote string in request creation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I hope you can help me, because I'm really close to hand myself with an usb cable ;)

So, my problem is very "simple": When I try to create a new object to insert in my database, Eloquent don't quote the string type attribute.
I know, it's strange.

I put you some code.

This is my model:

```
class Ue extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'nomUe',
        'idUser',
    ];
}
```

here, my function:

```
public function addNewUe(Request $request){

    $ue = Ue::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($ue, 201);
}
```

my controller: 
`Route::post('/ue', 'UeController@addNewUe');`

and then, my migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ues', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nomUe');
        $table->integer('idUser')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('idUser')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: insert into `ues` (`nomUe`, `idUser`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, 1, 2018-03-05 17:05:22, 2018-03-05 17:05:22))"
```

To test my request, I use postman, pic here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHg0s.jpg

As you can see, the value test is not quoted. Have you any idea ?
I hope you can help me, so thanks in advance for your help, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: That error message sounds like there's an issue connecting to MySQL, rather than anything to do with quoting.

Comment: The error you are getting `no such file or directory` might be because of a bad MySQL Connection, or invalid SQL Lite file. The line that you see through the debugger doesn't necessarily mean the values passed aren't quoted.

Comment: Ok, I try the connection to the BD is Ok. I run `php artisan tinker`, and try : `DB::connection('mysql')->getDatabaseName()` and i get : `"anthony-bertrant_geekadvisor_api"` and it's my db name

Comment: In fact, @Fredster and you're right. Apparently, laravel can't connect to my db. But, the previous week, I worked on my other pc and everything was correct. But now, even my old function, who were work, doesn't now. So, I need to figure out why everything got insane. Thanks for your help, if you have any idea of what I need to check first, tell me. thanks again for your help.

Comment: I found ! In fact, I restart larval server and run `php artisan serve`. Now, everything works back again ! thanks guys !

Comment: Great! Good for you!

Comment: @anthony .. great! then please answer the question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to solve my problem in local environment, I just restart the artisan serve of my application. When you restart it, everything works back.
To run the serve, just run: `php artisan serve`.

Thanks guy for your help ;)